# Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS starting vino / rdp from SSH

Tags: ssh, lightdm, remote-desktop, vino

Ok, this is a weird one. I created a custom image that I then uploaded to a cloud provider. I only have SSH access to the box, and would like to start a regular `lightdm`/`unity` session for another user I have on the box. To be clear I don't want to forward X session via SSH. I just want to SSH into the box, and start a RDP session for another user. Also I don't want to use `vnc` or `xstartup`.

`.xsession` file:

```
/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --session=ubuntu &
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity/unity-panel-service &
/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon &

for indicator in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-*; do
  basename=`basename ${indicator}`
  dirname=`dirname ${indicator}`
  service=${dirname}/${basename}/${basename}-service
  ${service} &
done

unity
```

Comment: Also every tutorial I've followed assumes that you have physical access to the box with physical display attached. Not something remote with only ssh access.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out, so I boot my headless Ubuntu 16.04

Then I install Xvfb

```
sudo apt-get install Xvfb
```

Next I install x11vncserver

```
sudo apt-get install x11vnc
```

And finally putting it all together to create the display attach unity and run vnc:

```
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &

DISPLAY=:10 unity &

x11vnc -auth /home/USSERNAME/.Xauthority -display :10 -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/USERNAME/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared
```